# How to store constant data inside flutter project?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a Flutter app in which I have three screens:

1. Services
2. Premium Packages
3. Profile

In services screen, the user will see 4 services (4 services for now, but only 1 or 2 services may be added every now and then). In Premium Packages screen the user will see 4 packages (again, only 1 or 2 additional packages may be added later such as "family package"). Each service and each package have titles and descriptions, in addition, each package has a list of offers.

To implement the UI in a less hard-coded way, I have created a `service` entity and a `package` entity, with fields like title, description for `service` entity, and title, description, list of offers for `package` entity.

Then I have created services file which holds a list of services, and a packages file which holds a list of packages. Then I map these lists to corresponding UI components like `service_item` and `package_item`.

My question is, is this the correct way of holding this kind of constant data? My question may sound stupid, but please bare with me, since it's my first time working on a "real" project and I don't know any better way of asking it.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate file name as `constants.dart` and `create a class` something called a Constant. All your constant Items should be there something like below.

```
class Constants {
  static const String loginButtonString = 'Login Now';
}
```

and you can use it anywhere you wanted for example

```
Text(Constants.loginButtonString)
```